# How to get a function to return different types

Tags: haskell

So, I have a function with multiple definitions (guards), and depending on which one it matches, I'm trying to have it either return an (a,b) or [(a,b)], however the compiler is throwing up errors 'cause they're different types. I was trying to use Either to solve this, but probably not using it right :P. any help?

Comment: You cannot do that directly because the return type of the function must be known at compile time, while the guards are matched at run time.

But are you sure you really want to return a different type ? If you intend to pattern match on the result to distinguish the two cases, Either is fine. Or maybe a singleton list will do in the first case ? Can you provide more details about what you're going to do ?

Comment: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/325066/ is my function so far

Comment: that's like reading a magic spell.  What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: I'm trying to convert my lua program of euler probleem #4 -- https://github.com/saiko-chriskun/Project-Euler/blob/master/4.lua

this is what I have so far -- http://paste.pocoo.org/show/325087/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Either` -- or a custom data type equivalent to it -- is the only way to do this.  Here's a dumb example:

```
stuff :: Int -> Either (Int,Int) [(Int,Int)]
stuff 0 = Left (0, 0)
stuff n = Right [ (x,x) | x <- [0..n] ]
```

Then when somebody calls this function, they can pattern match to find out which of the two types it returned:

```
foo n = case stuff n of
            Left (a,b) -> ...
            Right pairs -> ...
```

However, knowing nothing about your problem, in general I would recommend thinking a bit more about the meaning of your function.  What does it take, what does it return?  Be precise, mathematical. The simpler the answer, the more smoothly this function will work with the rest of your program and the concepts of Haskell.  For me, in such descriptions, `Either` rarely turns up.  How can you unify the two results?  Maybe you just return the singleton list `[(a,b)]` instead of `Left (a,b)`, if that makes sense for your function.

Haskell does not play well with functions that try to be too smart, the type that you may be used to from Python or jQuery.  Keep it dumb and precise -- get your complexity from *composing* these simple pieces.  If you are curious about this, ask another question with more details about your problem, what you are trying to accomplish, and why you want it to work that way.  Sorry for the preaching :-)

Comment: Let me add that the property we want of the type system is that of *preservation*: Loosely speaking if we had the type `stuff :: Int -> (Int, Int)` then a call to `stuff 7` say would reduce to `[ (x,x) | x <- [0..n ]` in the example which has type `[(Int, Int)]`. This is different from the proclaimed return type of `stuff` and hence the type would not be preserved. If we are to trust the type system for anything, this discrepancy must be ruled out. So the type checker rejects our program as being ill-typed.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in Haskell can only return one type so Either will work for you since it would have your function return the type Either (a,b) [(a.b)].

I am not sure what went wrong with how you are using Either but here is a simple example of its usage:

```
test a b = 
    if a == True 
    then Left (a,b) 
    else Right [(a,b)]
```

Comment: so here's my function now: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/325090/

here's the error: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/325093/

Comment: @Chris `Right lgst i` should be `Right (lgst i)`.

Comment: ok so http://paste.pocoo.org/show/325143/ works, however the latter two guards need to look something like http://paste.pocoo.org/show/325144/ which gives me: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/325145/