# Haskell: overload siginiture and return different results for different input types

Tags: haskell

I need this function:

```
blubb :: ??? -> Int
blubb (n :: Int) = n
blubb (n :: Char) = 42
```

This is how it should work: the function gets an `Int` and returns it. If the function gets an `Char` it returns a constant value and the other cases are indifferent.

Because of the type system in Haskell it might be not possible but I need to get this working ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what type classes are for:

```
class Blubb t where
    blubb :: t -> Int


instance Blubb Int where
    blubb n = n

instance Blubb Char where
    blubb _ = 42
```

This overloads `blubb` to work on both `Int`s and `Char`s.  The compiler will select the correct one to use based off of the type of the argument.

However, be careful that you are not using type classes where you actually wanted an `Either`.  You may have actually wanted this:

```
blubb :: Either Int Char -> int
blubb (Left  n) = n
blubb (Right _) = 42
```

Comment: I've read about `Data.Either` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770910/how-to-get-a-function-to-return-different-types). Does this allow me to have two different input types?

Comment: Might be a stupid question: but how do I use your code? I understand what it does but not how to use.

Comment: @mythbu I just updated my answer to add the `Either` version.  It lets you store an alternative between two types within the same value.  So when you say something has type `Either a b`, you are saying that it could "either" be an `a` or a `b`, but not both at the same time.

Comment: @mythbu It would help if you expanded your question to show where you wanted to use `blubb`.  Then I could give you more specific advice.

Comment: Oh ... now I understand the logic behind the type classes concept. But currently. It's exactly that for what I'm looking. But currently I have some trouble with the example call `blubb 9`, because `:t 9` is `Num`. Is there any way to force Int input?

Comment: @mythbu That sounds like a case for `Either` rather than a type class.

Comment: @mythbu If you pass a literal or the polymorphic result of a function, you need a type signature, `foo (9 :: Int)`.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Yes, this works (`blubb (9 :: Int)`). Thx. But many to type for me. But I can't change the type class to Num, because Haskell expects a second argument (?).

Comment: How do I call the blubb function using Either (from top)?

Comment: `blubb (Left 9)`. Then you don't have a problem with specifying that `9` shall be an `Int` here, that's automatic, since `blubb` isn't polymorphic.

Comment: This isn't good: I get a plain `9` (or any other Int) or `'x'` (or any other Char and need to "translate" it using `blubb`. I can't modify the input with keywords ("Left"/"Right") ...

Comment: @mythbu: you "get" a plain 9? Where from? If this is some kind of user input thing then you're using entirely the wrong approach, you need to write a _parser_. Which is not too difficult with e.g. parsec, but you should have some understanding about how the type system works in principle before tackling something like that. – Have you read a proper Haskell tutorial? [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) will teach you all you need to know (including parsers), but perhaps you should rather start with [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).