# Haskell: writing an function to add Ints and Chars which are mapped by a function to Ints

Tags: haskell

The code bellow works pretty well for input like this:

```
*Main> eval 'y' (21 :: Int)
42
*Main> eval 'x' 'a'
42
*Main> eval (21 :: Int) (21 :: Int)
42
*Main> eval (42 :: Int) 'a'
42
```

The general problem behind this is that I want to add two things. Adding to `Int`s is not hard to realize (it's already built in). But I've a given function (here `geti`) which resolves `Char`s to `Int`s and my `add`-function now should add two `Int`s as well as `Int` combined with `Char` (in every permutation). The `Char`s are converted by the `geti` function to `Int`s so that they can be added. I've thought about an other solution which might be:

```
eval (geti 'a') (42 :: Int)
```

but that is not possible for me.

**So in general my question is: is there any way to make this simpler or implement it more elegant?**

*This is the code:*

```
-- A static function only used to resolve some demo data
geti :: Char -> Int
geti c | c == 'x' = 42
       | c == 'y' = 21
       | c == 'z' = 10
       | otherwise = 0


-- Here comes the problem:
class Eval t1 t2 where 
    eval :: t1 -> t2 -> Int

instance Eval Int Int where
    eval a b = a + b

instance Eval Int Char where
    eval a c = a + (geti c)

instance Eval Char Int where
    eval c b = (geti c) + b

instance Eval Char Char where
    eval c1 c2 = (geti c1) + (geti c2)
```

P.S.: I've also tried to combine the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304765/haskell-overload-siginiture-and-return-different-results-for-different-input-ty/14304833#comment19872020_14304833) with an "generic" (yes, it's Java language, but I'm new to Haskell ... sry) function but that didn't work ...

Comment: You have a problem, and you are trying to solve it in Haskell in the same way that you would solve it in Java. I don't think this will work. I think you should post your actual problem instead of the bits that you don't know how to do in Haskell. I think this is an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Comment: "but that is not possible for me" ― why? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it would be more straight forward to build a type class for "can be converted to `Int`" and use that to implement `eval`:

```
class Intable a where
   intify :: a -> Int

instance Intable Int where
   intify = id

instance Intable Char where
   intify = geti


eval :: (Intable a, Intable b) => a -> b -> Int
eval a b = intify a + intify b
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution I've looking for. Thx! Calls like `eval 'x' (0 :: Int)` work perfectly. Isn't it possible to get `eval 'x' 0` working? `ghci` says `... Ambiguous type variable `b0' in the constraints: ...`

Comment: @mythbu: You probably have to add an instance for `Integer`, like `intify = fromInteger`

Comment: @mythbu It is probably better to use the built in Enum class, from the prelude, and its fromEnum :: a -> Int method, since it seems to fit your design criteria, defined for many types already and will more easily recognized by other Haskell programmers.

Comment: @Davorak I was going to suggest that too, but it seems to have a different behavior than the one he's asking for on `Char`s.